# How to set value for file input form ? And how to do display it?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I want to display selected image in the edit.blade.php But I dont know how can I do this ?

```
Form::file('image',['value'=>'$post->featured_image'])
<!-- or -->
<input file="file" name="image" value="$post->featured_image">
```

But, both of doesn't work ? Is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Is the image posted/saved in this view?

Comment: Created in create.blade.php now ı want to edit it (change or remove) in edit.blade.php

Comment: If you have saved the image to post, use <img src = {!! asset('path/to/saved/featured_img') !!}/>

Comment: I know that but when I upload the new image, old one still there.. I want to change it

Comment: Please show your full edit.blade.php

Comment: @jeugen you would use {{ asset('') }} for the src right? Also, Hasan, if you are wanting to display the image dynamically as it is selected you may want to use JavaScript to change the src property of the image onscreen.

Comment: @MattMcAlister I have no idead js/ajax.. :( It seems I need to start to learn..

Comment: @MattMcAlister I also asked dynamically showing when upload, but Hasan mentioned, image is needed to show on edit page and image is already saved (see 2. comment)